# Use Enum values as Properties in

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I have an enum below:

```
private enum MovieData { Name, Type, Size, Description, ReleaseDate };
```

Now I want to use values of enum as property names as

```
public string MovieData.Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;                                
        }
    }
```

Same for others and name is an attribute. Return type of all should be string and I want to access the property with just Name not MovieData.Name

How can I do this?

Comment: The question is : why you want to do this ?
Could you write some more about it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, `public string MovieData.Name` is not valid C#. Could you give a more extensive example of what you mean by it? How you'd use it, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want an enum at all, but that `MovieData` should be a `class` with properties like `public string Name {get; set;}`.

Comment: My Instructor told me to use properties as enum. How can I do this?

Comment: @UmairJameel you can have a property that is of an `enum` *type*. `public enum MovieCat { Horror, Romance, Comedy }` -> `public MovieCat Category {get;set;}`

Comment: The attributes that I want to get and set are of string type, but here return type is MovieCat, how can I convert this to string? 
I am new in C#

Comment: Well, what exactly the setter Set{ } will do?

Comment: @UmairJameel I think you need to talk to your instructor and clarify exactly what they mean, because you are not understanding how `enum` works in C#. `enum` is used for making a sort of named range of values as in my above example. You *can* get a string value, but the usefulness is in using the `enum`s as is.

Comment: Thank you every one, I am got a solution after reading all this. Actually I was a bit wrong in understanding question from my Intrustor. sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm not sure what is your question, but as @crashmstr commented .. it seems you don't need an `Enum` but you just need a class to hold these properties**

Any way you can use this **BUT IT'S NOT A GOOD PRACTICE** 
and I don't know what do you want the `setter`  to do

```
public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return MovieData.Name.ToString();
            }
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return MovieData.Type.ToString();
            }
        }

        public string Size
        {
            get
            {
                return MovieData.Size.ToString();
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return MovieData.Description.ToString();
            }
        }

        public string ReleaseDate
        {
            get
            {
                return MovieData.ReleaseDate.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a `string` or the `enum` back?

```
private class SomeClass
{
    private MovieData _data;

    public MovieData Data { get { return _data; } set { _data = value; } }
    public string DataString 
    { 
        get { return _data.ToString(); }
        set {
            switch (value){
                case "Name":
                    _data = MovieData.Name;
                    break;
                case "Type":
                    _data = MovieData.Type;
                    break;
                // etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm still pretty unclear on what you're asking.